# Adding named rows to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Maybe this is too simple of a question, but I'm trying to add 2 more *named rows* to data.frame `d` below without success.

Would you please help me understand what I'm missing, and correcting my approach?

```
d <- data.frame(ESL = 1:5, prof = 0:4, scope = 2:6, type = 3:7)
rownames(d) <- LETTERS[1:5]
d[6:7,] <- c(com = 0:3, min = 2:5)
d

# DESIRED OUTPUT:
#   ESL prof scope type
# A   1    0     2    3
# B   2    1     3    4
# C   3    2     4    5
# D   4    3     5    6
# E   5    4     6    7
# com 0    1     2    3
# min 2    3     4    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rbind()` on the named vectors.

```
rbind(d, com = 0:3, min = 2:5) 

    ESL prof scope type
A     1    0     2    3
B     2    1     3    4
C     3    2     4    5
D     4    3     5    6
E     5    4     6    7
com   0    1     2    3
min   2    3     4    5
```

Comment: More generalisably, you should probably be rbinding `list`s to the bottom of `d`, like: `rbind(d, com=list(0,1,2,3), min=list(2,3,4,5))`. This would allow you to add a single row while matching varying column types if necessary.

Comment: @rnorouzian - `list(rep(TRUE,4))` and `list(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)` are not the same. You need the latter, or `as.list(rep(TRUE,4))` in shorter code. Adding `TRUE`s will also see them converted to numeric to match the existing data.

Comment: @rnorouzian - not really, you're trying to do something like `c(TRUE,1)`, which won't work. You could convert everything to character, but that changes your data type.

Comment: @rnorouzian - A `list` in each column would work to mix types, but that is ugly and not very easy to work with. Possible though. `d[] <- lapply(d, as.list); rbind(d, com=rep(list(list(TRUE)),4))` but not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Use rbind to form the right hand side and specify the rownames on the left hand side.

```
d[c("com", "min"),] <- rbind(0:3, 2:5)
```